# Context initialization failed applicationContext

Tags: java, spring, gradle, applicationcontext

I'm trying to make a spring web project using Gradle as project builder.

I devide it in two distincts one. A back-end project and a front-end project. The problem is that the front-end project can't initialise context because it don't find the "applicationContext.xml" file from the back-end project. My configuration is as follow :

Back-end project :

1- applicationContext.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/database" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>

    <!-- JPA EntityManagerFactory -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
        </property>
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="LiveLizard-persistenceUnit" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaDialect">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect">
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop><!-- create -->
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop><!-- false -->
                <prop key="hibernate.show_comments">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- <context:component-scan base-package="fluxa.admin.domain.Impl"></context:component-scan> -->
    <!-- Transaction manager for a single JPA EntityManagerFactory (alternative 
        to JTA) -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
        p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" />

    <!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes for eg 
        @Autowired -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <context:annotation-config />



    <!-- Property Configurator -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.nostatikmedia.livelizard.domain.repository.impl"></context:component-scan>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.nostatikmedia.livelizard.service.impl"></context:component-scan>

</beans>
```

2- build.gradle file :

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.2.3.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}") 
        classpath("io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.1.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot' 
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management' 

jar {
    baseName = 'demo'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.6.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.6.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-tx:4.1.6.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.1.6.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-orm:4.1.6.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Draft-16'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.8.Final'
    compile 'org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.5'
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.35'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.8.Final'
    compile 'junit:junit:4.4'
    compile 'javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.1.3.Final'
}


eclipse {
    classpath {
         containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
         containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7'
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}
```

Front-end project:

1- springmvcdispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath*:applicationContext.xml" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.nostatikmedia.livelizard.controller"></context:component-scan>
    <context:annotation-config />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping"></bean>
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

2- build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'

webAppDirName = 'WebContent'

repositories{
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies{
    compile project('LiveLizard-BackEndGradle')
    compile 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.2'
    compile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.6.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.6.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.1.6.RELEASE'
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
    }
}

eclipse {
    wtp {
        facet {
            facet name: 'jst.web', version: '3.1'
            facet name: 'java', version: '1.7'
            facet name: 'wst.jsdt.web', version: '1.0'
        }
        component{
            contextPath = 'livelizard'
        }
    }
}
```

And when i run the project in tomcat v8.0.22 i have this error message :

```
GRAVE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath*:applicationContext.xml]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springmvcdispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx]
Offending resource: URL [jar:file:/home/mind-in-motion/Documents/WorkspaceSts/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/LiveLizard-FrontEndGradle/WEB-INF/lib/LiveLizard-BackEndGradle.jar!/applicationContext.xml]
```

Comment: your `applicationContext.xml` is being found, you get an error because the namespace `tx:` is not being resolved. Make sure the 'org.springframework:spring-tx:4.1.6.RELEASE' dependency is transitively inherited by the frontend project

Comment: Thanks, it was it :) i missed some dependecies on front-end project. 
Tank you for help